# How to remove specific element from a list only one time in C++?

Tags: c++, list

I am trying to make a simple win32 console application in C++, that would count how many matches are with same scores.

Example:
match one score is 1:1
match two score is 1:1
match three score is 1:2

The program should print in the console this:
There are 2 matches with score 1:1
There are 1 matches with score 1:2

I have created "`match`" object.

```
class match
{   

 public:
    int hostScore;
    int guestScore;

    match();
   ~match();
    void input();//This method is to input data in the object.
};
```

Now I want to create function to count the matches with same score.

```
void count(list<match> a)
{
     match game;
     int counter;

     do{
           game = a.front(); // I want to take the value of the first element in the list and assign it to "game".

           do{
                  a.deleteSpecificValueOnlyOneTime(game);// I want to delete list element with the value of "game" 1 time
                  counter++

           } while (I can DeleteSpecificValuesOneTime)

           cout<<"There are <<counter<<" matches with score <<game.hostScore<< ":" << game.guestScore<<endl;
           counter = 0;

      } while (a != a.Empty();)// While a is not empty.
}
```

The idea is to take the value from the first element from the list, delete it one time, count it, and repeat the process until all elements with same values are deleted and to count how many time this happen.

Take the value of the n-th element and do the same.

Comment: You might want to store the information in a [`std::mulitiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)

Comment: hash tables are really good for counting things. Look into [unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/)

Comment: You can also use some higher level algorithms from the standard library, such as std::unique and std::count. You'll need to include <algorithm>. This is not for best performance, but it yields safer and shorter code.

Comment: Can I do it with list, or should I consider other data structure ?

Comment: You have a logic error: Delete only the first match of the list (which appears to be not a std::list) and iterating until the list is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use erase method in a while loop:

```
std::list<match>::iterator it = a.begin();
while (it != a.end())
{
    if (*it EQUALS game)
        it = a.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        it++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to put all elements in a set and than retrieve them back to the list.

In order to be able to do so you must define a less operator for match:

```
bool operator<(const match &lhs, const match &rhs){
  if(lhs.hostScore==rhs.hostScore){
    return lhs.guestScore<rhs.guestScore;
  }
  return lhs.guestScore<rhs.guestScore;
}
```

after that you are almost done fast done:

```
void make_elements_unique(std::list<match> &games){
  std::set<match> unique;
  //put all elements into the set:
  unique.insert(games.begin(), games.end());
  //clear list and copy all elements from the set to the list, they are unique:
  games.assign(unique.begin(), unique.end());
}
```

If you look for performance and have a lot of games, than unordered_set (c++11) would be a better option than std::set.